# How to test for no interaction using Mockito

Tags: java, testing, mockito

I'm currently studying the book written by Tomasz Kaczanowski: "Practical Unit Testing with JUnit and Mockito". Right now, I'm on the section concerning mocks, stubs, test doubles and the Mockito framework.

As part of the practice, there's a to-be-unit-tested program which sends messages to the subscribed clients. Here's the part of the exercise I'm currently struggling with.

---

- What should happen if a client that is not subscribed tries to unsubscribe? Make up your mind about it, write a test which verifies this behaviour, and make RaceResultsService behave accordingly.

---

I would like *nothing* to happen on such occasion. No exception, no messages... And I want to test it. But how do I do that? How do I test that *nothing* happens (without getting too deep into implementation and, for example, checking the size of collection containing subscribed clients)?

Here's the test I've written which does not do so:

```
@Test
void unsubscribingWhenAlreadyUnsubscribedShouldReturnVoid() {
    raceResults.removeSubscriber(clientA);

    verifyNoInteractions(clientA);
}
```

And here's the concerned method of the `RaceResultsService.java`:

```
public class RaceResultsService {

    private Collection<Client> clients = new HashSet<Client>();

    // other fields and methods

    public void removeSubscriber(Client client) {
        clients.remove(client);
    }
}
```

Obviously, the `removeSubscriber` method will actually do *something*, not nothing. It will execute the `HashSet.remove` but, as the client is not in the `clients` collection (field), it will not modify anything. But how do I test for this without actually touching the associated `Collection<Client>`?

I'd appreciate any suggestions, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It would be hard to test that *nothing* happens. But you shouldn't: a unit test should only test *observable* behaviour. Whatever happens inside the implementation is not the test's concern.

For example, if the implementation is changed to write a warning to a log file to inform the developers that a client might be buggy, this should probably not break the test. (You could argue that logging is also observable behaviour, but it's not usually part of the contract.)

So, what *should* you test for in this case?

Your test is already testing something, namely, that `raceResults.removeSubscriber(clientA);` does not throw an exception. In other words, it verifies that it's not an error to remove a client that's not subscribed. This might already be enough!

If you also have a method like `boolean isSubscribed(Client client)`, you could additionally verify that the client is not subscribed after unsubscribing.

You could also send a message and verify that the unsubscribed client does not receive it.